# Automatizar el habilitado de botones

Tags: delphi

Tengo un Form en Delphi que añade elementos a una lista(ListBox) y las puede  mover a otra lista (ListBox);

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que deseo hacer es que los botones(BitBtn) que mueven los elementos de una lista a otra se desactiven automáticamente cuando las dos listas estén vacías. Entonces, ¿ Cómo puedo hacer que este proceso esté activo durante la ejecución de mi aplicación?

[image: En esta captura inhabilité manualmente los botones]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes declarar un método que se encargue de actualizar el estado de los botones, por ejemplo:

```
type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    lstIzquierda: TListBox;
    lstDerecha: TListBox;
    btnADerecha: TBitBtn;
    btnAIzquierda: TBitBtn;
  private
    procedure ActualizarUI;
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm3.ActualizarUI;
begin
  btnADerecha.Enabled := lstIzquierda.Items.Count > 0;
  btnAIzquierda.Enabled := lstDerecha.Items.Count > 0;
end;
```

Luego, cada vez que cambia el contenido de una lista, llamas al método AcutalizarUI, por ejemplo, una hipotética implementación del onClick de uno de los botones (sin soporte para multi-selección) podría ser:

```
procedure TForm3.btnADerechaClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if lstIzquierda.ItemIndex >= 0 then
  begin
    lstDerecha.Items.Add(lstIzquierda.Items[lstIzquierda.ItemIndex]);
    lstIzquierda.Items.Delete(lstIzquierda.ItemIndex);
    ActualizarUI;
  end;
end;
```

Si lees el código con atención, en lugar de activar y desactivar ambos botones de acuerdo al contenido de ambas listas, desactivo uno por uno en base al contenido de una sola de las listas, que supongo que es lo que realmente persigues.

Comment: Es una forma tan ingeniosa de hacerlo, para mí que inicié en este entorno, es muy bueno. Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Yo aprovecharía esta pregunta para recomendarte que utilizaras Actions.
Una [TAction](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.ActnList.TAction) es un elemento que puedes asociar a un botón, a un elemento de un menú, o a varios de ellos y sirve para centralizar las acciones que realizas y el estado de los elementos a los que la asocias.
te permite tener un código más organizado y evitar llamadas repeticas y copias de código.

De esta forma, si creas una `TAction` para cada botón, a través de una `TActionList` y la asocias a tus botones te ofrece 2 ventajas.

1. El código asociado al botón pasa a la `TAction` (y queda centralizado). Para ello utilizas el evento (`OnExecute`).
2. El estado del botón también se controla con la `TAction`. Para ello utilizas el evento (`OnUpdate`).

El código del evento `OnExecute` es el mismo que tienes ahora en cada botón y el den evento `OnUpdate` sería algo así:

```
  ActionADerecha.Enabled := lstIzquierda.Items.Count > 0;
```

La ventaja es que no te tienes que preocupar de cuando debes actualizar el estado. Las `TAction` lo hacen por tí.